# All .pdf text have gray background color

Tags: pdf, fonts, thunderbird

I have no idea why but since several days, all my .pdf opened with Thunderbird appear to have a gray background for the fonts instead of the usual white. Do you know how to fix it? I couldn't find in Thunderbird settings. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

When I open them in Chrome or Document Viewer, everything is fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue probably comes from custom text and background colors (i.e. different from black for text and white for background) in Preferences > General > Fonts & Colors > Colors...

I believe this is a Thunderbird bug (reported at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1771813).

One easy fix is obviously to bypass the Thunderbird preview mechanism and have Thunderbird open the pdf attachments in a separate app

Or, if it is not acceptable, one can revert the colors to black text over white background in the Colors dialog, and/or select 'Only with High Contrast themes' (this may depend on your OS theme) or 'Never' as the 'Override the colors specified by the content with my selections above' option. However with this setting it will no longer be possible to display HTML messages with light text over dark background - which was the reason why I customized the colors in the first place on my side.